# Can't save the changes i made in the VSCode

Tags: javascript, linux, visual-studio-code, root

Everything was working fine, I was creating a weather app. I made it, but later I thought to make some other request. And I got an error that says can't save the files. I was working in "vs code". Can anybody help me to fix this? I don't know what went wrong. I am using Linux mint. Below is the error I got from "vs code" whenever I try to save the file.

> Failed to save 'script.js': Unable to write file
>   '/home/p4avinash/Desktop/Practice and
>   Learn/PracticeFetching/weatherApp/script.js' (Unknown
>   (FileSystemError): Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open
>   '/home/p4avinash/Desktop/Practice and
>   Learn/PracticeFetching/weatherApp/script.js')

Answer (score 1):

Your file system may be corrupt. You will need to fsck to your mounted file system to eliminate this error. Go to the terminal and try fsck -fy /dev/sda1 or fsck -fy /dev/sda2 or sda3. It should be one of those ones. When you are done, reboot your system and you should be good.

Answer (score -1):

This might be happening because the destination where you're trying to save the code is a read-only directory. Try changing the permissions to read and write for the owner as well as others(if you are not logged in as root user).

Comment: You should provide an example of how to `Try changing the permissions to read and write for the owner as well as others`

Answer (score -1):

Edit:
I think when you create new files in the running session of VS code, the files need to have the permissions to be updated in the user directory.
So, if you run VSCode as Administrator, you can create and save new files without any problem. Because it automatically assigns permissions to newly created files.
This error message is a bit misleading and led me to change file permission using `sudo chown` command, which should be avoided unless required.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have updated the response by adding more context.

Answer (score -1):

This may be because the file/destination permissions have changed to read-only. You need to make it writable. Use the command

```bash
chmod -R u+w /path-to-your-directory
```

Comment: There error clearly says that the entire file system is read only, not just the directory.